# Orchard - Wrappers for Fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm trying to use a wrapper view for fields in a custom form but when I do the wrapper content shows up fine but I lose my field. I've looked over [this tutorial on placement](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info) and I'm trying to use the wrapper functionality to get separators into my custom form to break up the questions but it's not working.

For example I've got a question on my form that asks for Name. in my placement file I have the following

```
<!-- content:2.[section].[questionNumber] -->
<Place Fields_Common_Text_Edit-Name="Content:2.1.1"/>
<Place Fields_Input_Edit-PhoneNumber="Content:2.1.2"/>
...
```

And this works fine, but I want to put a series of seperator headers between certain groups/sections of questions, for example this one is "General Information"

So I change my placement file's line for the Name to this...

```
<Place Fields_Common_Text_Edit-Name="Content:2.1.1;Wrapper=GeneralInfoHeader"/>
<Place Fields_Input_Edit-PhoneNumber="Content:2.1.2"/>
```

And this works perfectly, my header shows up , but now my question for Name is gone and my first visible question is for Phone Number. According to the tutorial I used, my wrapper view looks like this

```
<h3>General Information</h3>
<hr>
@Model.Html
```

But the line of @Model.Html doesn't actually output my field. How do I get the wrapper to work for Fields? (Orchard 1.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well a wrapper is just a separate piece of Razor code that act like a parent of your view. So you need to tell them to display your content.

So you need to have `@Display(Model.Metadata.ChildContent)` in your wrapper to display the field itself.

Comment: Nope, I just tried it and I still don't get the actual field. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry I got the syntax wrong, try @Display(Model.Metadata.ChildContent)

Comment: That was it! Thanks a bunch! Now because these are all clay shapes, how do you find the correct properties and such if you don't know them?

Comment: Have you got Shape Tracing installed?

Comment: Well, if you haven't you can get it from the orchard gallery. http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.DesignerTools This is pretty much the ultimate tool for doing anything ^^ Install it and enable the Shape Tracing feature. Then you will have a bar at the bottom of your screen in the front end that you can open and then click on fields, content items etc and learn everything about them. Alternate shapes, placement, properties of the Model etc. etc. Reduces a little of the initial pain that you suffer when starting the dive into Orchard. A little ;)

Comment: I do, but after checking through the Model in the shape tracing panel, I don't see any property on it called Metadata so I'm not sure how I would have ever found that. Shape Tracing is how I found the field names to use in my placement file.

Comment: Yeah I see your point, I cant see it either. It is something that should be clear in the documentation I guess. In fact, looks like the documentation is just wrong, which isn't particularly helpful. I think the docs are editable, maybe I will go and poke around there sometime. If a simple tutorial doesn't work for me I usually just give up xD Orchard cant afford that! It has like 10 people as it is ^^

Comment: Thank goodness I found this Post. I spent hours in the shape tracking tool trying to find this. How did you even know to look for the Metadata property at all?

Comment: Spend too long staring into the depths of Orchards source code. But since that will likely send you mad, check out Sebastien's Cheat Sheet. I personally am not a fan but a lot of people have found it really helpful, so kudos to him for making it. You can find it here: http://sebastienros.github.io/CheatSheet/