# Orchard Shape Wrapper

Tags: razor, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I'm following the Orchard documentation on Wrappers but couldn't wrap my head around it.
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info#Wrapper

According to the documentation, we were to create `Wrapper.HtmlContent.cshtml` and insert the following in it.

```
<div class="htmlWrapperContent">
    @Model.Html
</div>
```

But what is `Model.Html`? Is it a `Shape`? I know `Model` is the Shape itself. `Html` is not a built-in property of `Shape` or `IShape` so I figure it must be some custom property done through code, for example `shapeHelper.My_Shape(Html: "Hello World")`?

---

Let's start from the beginning with an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve. I have done the following:

**Placement.info**

```
<Placement>
    <Place My_Shape="Content:before;Wrapper=My_Wrapper" />
</Placement>
```

**My.Shape.cshtml**

```
<div class="myShape">
    @* let's pretend that the line below prints "Hello World" *@
    @Model.Html
</div>
```

**My.Wrapper.cshtml**

```
<div class="htmlWrapperContent">
    @* what should I be putting here? *@

    @* I have tried the following *@

    @* #1 *@
    <div class="myShape">
        @Model.Html
    </div>
    @* Obviously this works but then why would I use a wrapper to do this? I might as well just surround `My.Shape.cshtml` with `<div class="htmlWrapperContent"></div>` above. *@

    @* #2 *@
    @Display(Model)
    @* This doesn't work because circular reference. IIS killed itself. *@

    @* #3 *@
    @DisplayChildren(Model)
    @* Since `Model._items` is empty, this doesn't print anything. *@
</div>
```

My expectation of how the page should look like

```
<div class="htmlWrapperContent">
    <div class="myShape">
        Hello World
    </div>
</div>
```

So my question is, how should `My.Wrapper.cshtml` look like to meet my expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after posting my question, I found the answer here

[Orchard - Wrappers for Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487005/orchard-wrappers-for-fields)

So, the wrapper should be

**My.Wrapper.cshtml**

```
<div class="htmlWrapperContent">
    @Display(Model.Metadata.ChildContent)
</div>
```

The Orchard documentation could use some improvements.