# How to display wrapped item in a wrapper

Tags: orchardcms

I wanted to add a wrapper around my comments module.

I've set up the wrapper file (`\Views\Wrapper.Parts.Disqus.cshtml`);

I've added it in placement.info:

```
<Place Parts_Disqus="Content:20;Wrapper=Wrapper_Parts_Disqus" />
```

It finds it and wraps it but I cannot figure out what to put inside the middle of the wrapper to show its wrapped content.

I'm working with [Orchard.Cw.Disqus](https://github.com/carlwoodhouse/Orchard.Cw.Disqus).

I've looked around the Orchard source, sometimes its `@Display(Model.Child)` sometimes other things. I've tried many combinations.

What is the formula to understand what you should put inside a wrapper to make its show its wrapped content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like in my case it is

```
@Display(Model.Metadata.ChildContent)
```

Thanks:

- [Orchard Shape Wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165911/orchard-shape-wrapper)